# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using Hibernate and got the exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  What are the possible causes?

Comment: You tried to index an array... outside its bounds?

Comment: Must be something accessed a non existing index of some array! Thats all I can infer from your question

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException can occur whenever you try to access an array element using an index which is either less than 0 or greater than the [array size-1]. Try to post the code to get clear answers.

Comment: show some code ? Look at the stacktrace to see which code you should show

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it

Comment: I got this exception from Hibernate too. After restarting whole server, it gone. Maybe [@Testalonga's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3492578/419348) is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tried to access an index which is out of your array size i.e. `index < 0 or index >= array.length`.

For example `int[] myArray = new int[10];`
if you access `myArray[11]` you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Even if you access `myArray[10]` in that case you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks Jesper I agree with you. whenever array index satisfies index < 0 or index >= array.length condition we will  get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 9):

It's possible that Hibernate is throwing this exception in the case you use an old **[JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity)** driver with **Oracle**. At some point there was a bug in the JDBC diver with the **fetch-size**, meaning that if the fetch-size you use in Hibernate (hibernate.properties or in hibernate.cfg.xml) was not the same as in jdbc-level, you got an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

Answer (score 0):

You access some index out of the array size. For example, `myArray.get(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing an array with an index out of the size of the Array. It has to do nothing with hibernate.

Check in your code that the `index` variable is lower than `array.size()`