# What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arrayindexoutofboundsexception

What does `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` mean and how do I get rid of it?

Here is a code sample that triggers the exception:

```
String[] names = { "tom", "bob", "harry" };
for (int i = 0; i <= names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: In reference to the last question, code would be helpful.  Are you accessing the array with a known index, or do you have to start debugging to figure out how the index is calculated when the error occurs?

Comment: Replace `i <= name.length` with `i < name.length` - or better, write an enhanced for loop. (`for (String aName : name) { ... }`)

Comment: it means, that you want to get element of array that not exist, 'i<=name.length' means that you want to get element length+1 - its not exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: The array goes out of bounds when the index you try to manipulate is more than the length of the array. For correctness, your indices should always be one less than the total no. of array elements because the array index starts from 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 348, accepted):

Your first port of call should be the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) which explains it reasonably clearly:

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

So for example:

```
int[] array = new int[5];
int boom = array[10]; // Throws the exception
```

As for how to avoid it... um, don't do that. Be careful with your array indexes.

One problem people sometimes run into is thinking that arrays are 1-indexed, e.g.

```
int[] array = new int[5];
// ... populate the array here ...
for (int index = 1; index <= array.length; index++)
{
    System.out.println(array[index]);
}
```

That will miss out the first element (index 0) and throw an exception when index is 5. The valid indexes here are 0-4 inclusive. The correct, idiomatic `for` statement here would be:

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
```

(That's assuming you *need* the index, of course. If you can use the enhanced for loop instead, do so.)

Comment: I'd add that for multidimensional arrays that might have an arbitrary shape in Java, the nested loops should check for the relevant subarray length: `for (int nestedIndex = 0; nestedIndex < array[outerIndex].length; nestedIndex++) { ... array[outerIndex][nestedIndex] ... }`.

Comment: It would be could to mention in the answer that the stack trace should be consulted to find the exact line where the error occurs. IMO, this is the first port of call.

Comment: @rghome: That's not an answer to "What does ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException mean" though. I think before trying to understand what in your code causes it, you need to understand what it means. If I tell you that you've got a GrobulatorError in a given line of code, how would you expect to identify what's causing it if you have no idea what a GrobulatorError is?

Comment: Yes - but. We get a **lot** of these and there is a need to find a link for the close-as-duplicate. Often the OP hasn't even identified the line of code it happened on. There is another question on how to analyse a stack trace, but I am thinking it would be good to have a single procedure for finding the IOOB, so that someone can close the question confident that the OP can then solve it for themselves with the link.

Comment: @rghome: A canonical question and answer sounds fine, but I don't think this is necessarily the right one. Or even if it *is* the right one, I'd still say the first thing to do is understand what the error means, before looking in your code to see why it happens.

Answer (score 63):

Basically:

```
if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) {
    // Don't use this index. This is out of bounds (borders, limits, whatever).
} else {
    // Yes, you can safely use this index. The index is present in the array.
    Object element = array[index];
}
```

In your specific case,

```
for (int i = 0; i<=name.length; i++)
```

the index is inclusive the array's length. This is out of bounds. You need to replace `<=` by `<`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
```

#### See also:

- [The Java Tutorials - Language Basics - Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 30):

From this excellent article: [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in for loop](https://programming.guide/java/arrayindexoutofboundsexception-in-for-loop.html)

To put it briefly:

In the last iteration of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= name.length; i++) {
```

`i` will equal `name.length` which is an illegal index, since array indices are zero-based.

Your code should read

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) 
                  ^
```

Answer (score 19):

It means that you are trying to access an index of an array which is not valid as it is not in between the bounds.

For example this would initialize a primitive integer array with the upper bound 4.

```
int intArray[] = new int[5];
```

Programmers count from zero. So this for example would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the upper bound is 4 and not 5.

```
intArray[5];
```

Comment: Bounds are the limits within range. i.e.; 0-5

Answer (score 15):

**What causes `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?**

If you think of a variable as a "box" where you can place a value, then an array is a series of boxes placed next to each other, where the number of boxes is a finite and explicit integer.

Creating an array like this:

```
final int[] myArray = new int[5]
```

creates a row of 5 boxes, each holding an `int`. Each of the boxes has an index, a position in the series of boxes. This index starts at 0 and ends at N-1, where N is the size of the array (the number of boxes).

To retrieve one of the values from this series of boxes, you can refer to it through its index, like this:

```
myArray[3]
```

Which will give you the value of the 4th box in the series (since the first box has an index of 0).

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is caused by trying to retrieve a "box" that does not exist, by passing an index that is higher than the index of the last "box", or negative.

With my running example, these code snippets would produce such an exception:

```
myArray[5] //tries to retrieve the 6th "box" when there is only 5
myArray[-1] //just makes no sense
myArray[1337] //way to high
```

**How to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`**

In order to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, there are some key points to consider:

**Looping**

When looping through an array, always make sure that the index you are retrieving is strictly smaller than the length of the array (the number of boxes). For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
```

Notice the `<`, never mix a `=` in there..

You might want to be tempted to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
    final int someint = myArray[i - 1]
```

Just don't. Stick to the one above (if you need to use the index) and it will save you a lot of pain.

Where possible, use foreach:

```
for (int value : myArray) {
```

This way you won't have to think about indexes at all.

When looping, whatever you do, NEVER change the value of the loop iterator (here: `i`). The only place this should change value is to keep the loop going. Changing it otherwise is just risking an exception, and is in most cases not necessary.

**Retrieval/update**

When retrieving an arbitrary element of the array, always check that it is a valid index against the length of the array:

```
public Integer getArrayElement(final int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= myArray.length) {
        return null; //although I would much prefer an actual exception being thrown when this happens.
    }
    return myArray[index];
}
```

Answer (score 13):

To avoid an array index out-of-bounds exception, one should use the [enhanced-`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) statement where and when they can.

The primary motivation (and use case) is when you are iterating and you do not require any complicated iteration steps.  You would *not* be able to use an enhanced-`for` to move backwards in an array or only iterate on every other element.

You're guaranteed not to run out of elements to iterate over when doing this, and your [corrected] example is easily converted over.

The code below:

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};
for(int i = 0; i< name.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(name[i] + "\n");
}
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};
for(String firstName : name) {
    System.out.println(firstName + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your code you have accessed the elements from index 0 to the length of the string array. `name.length` gives the number of string objects in your array of string objects i.e. 3, but you can access only up to index 2 `name[2]`,
because the array can be accessed from index 0 to `name.length - 1` where you get `name.length` number of objects.

Even while using a `for` loop you have started with index zero and you should end with `name.length - 1`. In an array a[n] you can access form a[0] to a[n-1].

For example:

```
String[] a={"str1", "str2", "str3" ..., "strn"};

for(int i=0; i<a.length(); i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);
```

In your case:

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};

for(int i = 0; i<=name.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(name[i] +'\n');
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For your given array the length of the array is 3(i.e. name.length = 3). But as it stores element starting from index 0, it has max index 2.

So, instead of  'i**<=**name.length' you should write 'i**<**name.length' to avoid 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.

Answer (score 4):

So much for this simple question, but I just wanted to highlight a new feature in Java which will avoid all confusions around indexing in arrays even for beginners. Java-8 has abstracted the task of iterating for you.

```
int[] array = new int[5];

//If you need just the items
Arrays.stream(array).forEach(item -> { println(item); });

//If you need the index as well
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(index -> { println(array[index]); })
```

What's the benefit? Well, one thing is the readability like English. Second, you need not worry about the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 3):

The most common case I've seen for seemingly mysterious ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions, i.e. apparently not caused by your own array handling code, is the concurrent use of SimpleDateFormat. Particularly in a servlet or controller:

```
public class MyController {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

  public void handleRequest(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) {
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(req.getParameter("date"));
  }
}
```

If two threads enter the SimplateDateFormat.parse() method together you will likely see an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Note the synchronization section of the [class javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Make sure there is no place in your code that are accessing thread unsafe classes like SimpleDateFormat in a concurrent manner like in a servlet or controller. Check all instance variables of your servlets and controllers for likely suspects.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` due to `i<=name.length` part. `name.length` return the length of the string `name`, which is 3. Hence when you try to access `name[3]`, it's illegal and throws an exception.

Resolved code:

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) { //use < insteadof <=
  System.out.print(name[i] +'\n');
}
```

It's defined in the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The `public final` field `length`, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. `length` may be positive or zero.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Array index out of bounds exception]

That's how this type of exception looks when thrown in Eclipse. The number in red signifies the index you tried to access. So the code would look like this:

```
myArray[5]
```

The error is thrown when you try to access an index which doesn't exist in that array. If an array has a length of 3,

```
int[] intArray = new int[3];
```

then the only valid indexes are:

```
intArray[0]
intArray[1]
intArray[2]
```

If an array has a length of 1,

```
int[] intArray = new int[1];
```

then the only valid index is:

```
intArray[0]
```

Any integer equal to the length of the array, or bigger than it: is out of bounds.

Any integer less than 0: is out of bounds;

P.S.: If you look to have a better understanding of arrays and do some practical exercises, there's a video here: [tutorial on arrays in Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1i42DMrcMk)

Answer (score 3):

For multidimensional arrays, it can be tricky to make sure you access the `length` property of the right dimension. Take the following code for example:

```
int [][][] a  = new int [2][3][4];

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < a[j].length; k++){
            System.out.print(a[i][j][k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Each dimension has a different length, so the subtle bug is that the middle and inner loops use the `length` property of the same dimension (because `a[i].length` is the same as `a[j].length`).

Instead, the inner loop should use `a[i][j].length` (or `a[0][0].length`, for simplicity).

Comment: Added a code example from [Why does my for loop not work when i change the condition(multidimensional arrays)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50824437/1288) since this question gets used as a dupe target for any question dealing with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

**For any array of length n, elements of the array will have an index from 0 to n-1.**

If your program is trying to access any element (or memory) having array index greater than n-1, then Java will throw **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

So here are two solutions that we can use in a program

1. Maintaining count:

   ```
   for(int count = 0; count < array.length; count++) {
       System.out.println(array[count]);
   }
   ```

   Or some other looping statement like

   ```
   int count = 0;
   while(count < array.length) {
       System.out.println(array[count]);
       count++;
   }
   ```
2. A better way go with a for each loop, in this method a programmer has no need to bother about the number of elements in the array.

   ```
   for(String str : array) {
       System.out.println(str);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means that you are trying to access an index of the array that does not exist or out of the bound of this array. Array indexes start from **0** and end at **length - 1**.

In your case

```
for(int i = 0; i<=name.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(name[i] +'\n'); // i goes from 0 to length, Not correct
}
```

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` happens when you are trying to access 
the name.length indexed element which does not exist (array index ends at  length -1). just replacing <= with < would solve this problem.

```
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(name[i] +'\n');  // i goes from 0 to length - 1, Correct
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException whenever this exception is coming it mean you are trying to use an index of array which is out of its bounds or in lay man terms you are requesting more than than you have initialised.

To prevent this always make sure that you are not requesting a index which is not present in array i.e. if array length is 10 then your index must range between 0 to 9

Answer (score 2):

ArrayIndexOutOfBounds means you are trying to index a position within an array that is not allocated.

In this case:

```
String[] name = { "tom", "dick", "harry" };
for (int i = 0; i <= name.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(name[i]);
}
```

- name.length is 3 since the array has been defined with 3 String objects.
- When accessing the contents of an array, position starts from 0. Since there are 3 items, it would mean name[0]="tom", name[1]="dick" and name[2]="harry
- When you loop, since *i* can be less than or equal to name.length, you are trying to access name[3] which is not available.

To get around this...

- In your for loop, you can do i < name.length. This would prevent looping to name[3] and would instead stop at name[2]

  `for(int i = 0; i<name.length; i++)`
- Use a for each loop

  `String[] name = { "tom", "dick", "harry" };
  for(String n : name) {
      System.out.println(n);
  }`
- Use list.forEach(Consumer action) (requires Java8)

  `String[] name = { "tom", "dick", "harry" };
  Arrays.asList(name).forEach(System.out::println);`
- Convert array to stream - this is a good option if you want to perform additional 'operations' to your array e.g. filter, transform the text, convert to a map etc (requires Java8)

  `String[] name = { "tom", "dick", "harry" };
  ---  Arrays.asList(name).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  ---  Stream.of(name).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 1):

According to your Code :

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};
for(int i = 0; i<=name.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(name[i] +'\n');
}
```

If You check
System.out.print(name.length);

you will get 3;

that mean your name length is 3

your loop is running from 0 to 3 
which should be running either "0 to 2" or "1 to 3"

**Answer**

```
String[] name = {"tom", "dick", "harry"};
for(int i = 0; i<name.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(name[i] +'\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each item in an array is called an element, and each element is accessed by its numerical index. As shown in the preceding illustration, **numbering begins with 0**. The 9th element, for example, would therefore be accessed at index 8.

IndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown to indicate that an index of some sort (such as to an array, to a string, or to a vector) is out of range.

Any array X, can be accessed from [0 to (X.length - 1)]

Answer (score 1):

I see all the answers here explaining how to work with arrays and how to avoid the index out of bounds exceptions.  I personally avoid arrays at all costs.  I use the Collections classes, which avoids all the silliness of having to deal with array indices entirely.  The looping constructs work beautifully with collections supporting code that is both easier to write, understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` name itself explains that If you trying to access the value at the index which is out of the scope of Array size then such kind of exception occur.

In your case, You can just remove equal sign from your for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<name.length; i++)
```

The better option is to iterate an array:

```
for(String i : name )
      System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array's length to control iteration of a **for** loop, always remember that the index of the first item in an array is **0**. So the index of the last element in an array is one less than the array's length.

Answer (score -1):

This error is occurs at runs loop  overlimit times.Let's consider simple example like this,

```
class demo{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    int[] numberArray={4,8,2,3,89,5};

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<numberArray.length;i++){
        System.out.print(numberArray[i+1]+"  ");
    }
}
```

At first, I have initialized an array as 'numberArray'. then , some array elements are printed using for loop. When loop is running 'i' time , print the (numberArray[i+1] element..(when i value is 1, numberArray[i+1] element is printed.)..Suppose that, when i=(numberArray.length-2), last element of array is printed..When 'i' value goes to (numberArray.length-1) , no value for printing..In that point , 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' is occur.I hope to you could get idea.thank you !

Answer (score -1):

You can use Optional in functional style to avoid `NullPointerException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` :

```
String[] array = new String[]{"aaa", null, "ccc"};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    String result = Optional.ofNullable(array.length > i ? array[i] : null)
            .map(x -> x.toUpperCase()) //some operation here
            .orElse("NO_DATA");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
AAA
NO_DATA
CCC
NO_DATA
```

Answer (score -1):

An ArrayIdexOutOfBoundException occurs when you try to access an index of an array which does not exists. In your scenario when i = 3, you try to retrieve the 3rd index of the names array. But names array holds values up to 2nd index.

Since there are no value at 3rd index of the array, This Exception is thrown.